# Is there a way to get the language list from locales_config.xml programmatically?

Tags: android, android-locale

I'm very confused about this new language stuff on Android 13.

I have a `locales_config.xml` file and that works fine but the documentation makes it sound like I can use `LocaleListCompat` in order to let users with Android 12 or older select the language.

However I haven't found any way to query all the languages listed on `locales_config.xml` other than parsing the XMl but that just doesn't feel right, plus the names of the languages wouldn't be translated.

So how should I go about giving users a choice of languages from `locales_config.xml`?

Comment: have you checked this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74114067/get-list-of-locales-from-locale-config-in-android-13

Comment: Yes but unless I'm reading that incorrectly, they are parsing the xml and there are no localized names for each language. Maybe when they get the locale list it gets translated? but they are still parsing the xml, right?

Comment: Ok, so I think I can use this code to just get the language codes and then I can use the normal Locale library to get the display name, that will hopefully be localized.